# angular2 material design how to fill mat-card dynamically from dataSource?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I'm hoping someone here can help me. i have a dataSource array and i want to write this data dynamically into several mat-card elements. for example i have an array with a size of 200. now i want to write a certain amount of data, for example 30 data into a mat-card and then write a new mat-card with the next 30 data and so on until all data from my dataSource is written into mat-cards. i tried this with ngFor but i have very little knowledge of programming so i wanted to ask if you have a solution for me? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by chunking the data in the original array into a 2 dimensional array where item 0 is an array containing the first 30 items, item 1 an array containing the second 30 items etc. For example if you array was:

```
['this', 'is', 'some', 'data', 'that', 'will', 'be', 'rendered', 'in', 'the', 'cards']
```

the chunked array (assuming a chunk size of 3) would be:

```
 [['this', 'is', 'some'], ['data', 'that', 'will'], ['be', 'rendered', 'in'], ['the', 'cards']]
```

I've implemented the following function to chunk the data (just change the `3` to whatever chunk size you want):

```
readonly chunkSize: number = 3;

getChunkedData() {
  var chunkedData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i += this.chunkSize) {
    chunkedData.push(this.data.slice(i, i + this.chunkSize));
  }
  return chunkedData;
}
```

You can then use an `ngFor` to loop over the chunked array and render each item in a single card:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let data of getChunkedData()">
  <p *ngFor="let item of data">
    {{item}}
  </p>
</mat-card>
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpzast-4kvnuf?file=src/app/card-overview-example.ts) for a working demo.